# Disable NestInterceptor auto stringify

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify, nestjs-interceptor

I'm using the following NestInterceptor to add code, message and data to final response:

```
export class HttpResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({
                code: 200,
                message: 'ok',
                data: data
            }))
        );
    }
}
```

The result I expected:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message: "ok",
    "data": {
        "vip": 333,
        "enterprise": 14,
        "pension": 712
    }
}
```

The result I'm getting:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "ok",
    "data": "{\"vip\":333,\"enterprise\":14,\"pension\":712}"}
```

I don't want auto stringify data, what should I do?

Update: Removing `GlobalFilters` won't work, I only have `HttpResponseInterceptor` as the `GlobalInterceptors`

Comment: what's the type of `data` in that `map()`? `typeof data`

Comment: It's ``string`` which was unexpected, I return an object in controller

Comment: AFIAK nestjs won't serialize that by default. So something is changing that. Are you using some others interceptors or such?

Comment: Do you have other interceptors in use as well? The `data` being returned _should_ be an object unless you've explicitly serialized it before

Comment: No, I only have a ``GlobalFilter`` for error handing

Answer (score 1):

It was determined this came from Nestia's [`TypedRoute` feature](https://nestia.io/docs/core/TypedRoute/). Currently it looks like the only way around it is to not use the TypedRoute